# Refreshing TableLayout to show new rows inserted

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

**Background:**

I have created an Orders table in a database and I am manipulating it in two activities namely `CurrentOrders` and `NewOrders` respectively.

`CurrentOrders` activity shows the current orders stored inside the database in a `TableLayout`. And to add new orders to the table I have specified a button namely `addOrders` which when clicked loads `NewOrders` activity.

*CurrentOrders:*

```
public class CurrentOrders extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    private TableLayout table;
    populateTable(Cursor records){
           
           TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
           TextView product = new TextView(this);
           TextView price = new TextView(this);        

           product.setText(records.getString(1));        
           price.setText(records.getString(2));          
           row.addView(product);
           row.addView(price);

           table.addView(row);
    } 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_current_orders);
        
        Cursor cursor = db.query("orders", null, null,
                null, null, null, null);  

        table = findViewById(R.id.tab);             

        while(cursor.moveToNext())                 
           populateTable(cursor);
    }

    public void addOrders(View view){
       startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewOrders.class));        
    } 
}
```

`NewOrders` activity acts like a form by having a `TableLayout` whose cells/fields are specified as `EditText` in order to let user type the orders they want to store. And to save the orders inside the database I have specified a submit button which when clicked store the value of `EditText` inside the Orders table in database and then goes back to parent activity (`CurrentOrders`) to show all the orders in the database.

*NewOrders:*

```
public class NewOrders extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_orders);                        
    }

    public void submit(View view){
        
        TableLayout table = findViewById(R.id.newOrders);
        int count = table.getChildCount();
        
        for (int idx = 0; idx < count; idx++){

            TableRow row = (TableRow) table.getChildAt(idx);

            EditText product = (EditText) row.getChildAt(1);
            EditText price = (EditText) row.getChildAt(2);

            String productVal = product.getText().toString();
            double priceVal = Double.parseDouble(price.getText().toString());

            long result = db.insert(productVal, priceVal);           
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

I don't see new records inserted until an unless I reload the `CurrentOrders` activity. I want to show all the records (included new ones) without having to reload the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally created a simple solution:

First we need to modify our `startActivity` of `CurrentOrder` in such a way so that It receives data from `NewOrders` activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    
    // add newly added orders
    
    if (data != null) {
        String response = data.getStringExtra("newOrders");
        if (requestCode == RequestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK && !response.isEmpty()){
            String[] orders = response.trim().split(" ");
            for (String order : orders) {
                // get new orders from the database
                Cursor records = db.query("orders", null, "id = ?", 
                                          new String[] {String.valueOf(id)},
                                          null, null, null);
                records.moveToNext();
                populateTable(records);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `addOrders` method you need to replace `startActivity` with the following code:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewOrders.class), 2);
```

Now coming to `NewOrders` activity here I have created a string variable that stores id's of the newly created orders:

```
public class NewOrders extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    // created a string variable
    private String newOrdersId = "";

    // reset of the code

    public void submit(View view){
        
        // rest of the code
        
        for (int idx = 0; idx < count; idx++){
            
            // rest of the code 
            
            // record id's of orders inserted into the database
            newOrderId += result + " "; 
        }
        // reset of the code
    }
}
```

And lastly you need to send the data to `CurrentOrders` by overriding `onBackPressed` method like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    intent.putExtra("newOrders", newOrdersId);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```